# Is primary memory buffering the only way to access I/O devices and secondary storage?

Tags: cpu, buffer, computer-architecture

I'm not sure if this is the right stack exchange site to ask this question so sorry if it's not. If anyone can cite a good book which explains computer architecture in general (not for a specific computer), that would be helpful.

The question is asking if a hard disk is accessed by the CPU by first transferring a block of data from the hard disk into the RAM and then the CPU reads it from the RAM. The same happens with input and output devices, where RAM is always an intermediary store for all data transfer outside primary memory. Is this the case?

Comment: This is the electrical engineering site, so not the right place. However, for "large" general purpose computing systems such data is usually buffered. On small resource-limited systems like microcontrollers, buffers eat a lot of precious RAM so data is often handled a byte at a time.  Usually these processors aren't connected to devices that require a whole buffer to be transferred at once, like disk drives usually do.

Comment: Is there a better stack exchange site for this question? They all seem to be focused on the programming aspect of computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is an electrical engineering site, I will attempt to give a lower level perspective.

Any device, such as a hard disk controller, must have some way of transferring data. This could be a parallel data bus or a serial one, it could be through radio waves or it could even be through human read LEDs and human set DIP switches (thus not necessarily needing a CPU at all). So then, the question comes up: How is the best way to connect a device to the CPU? You could make the device look for a specific address on the CPU address bus and then it would send or recieve data only when the CPU reads or writes on that address. This would skip RAM entirely, allowing the CPU to copy data directly from the device to a processor register. Of course in your architecture you would have to make sure that there were no conflict and that RAM doesnt also respond to the request generating a bus collision. To avoid that, you could add a special IO line in your CPU architecture that is asserted to read and write from devices and disables the RAM. You could even add a special IO bus to the CPU architecture if you wanted.

This was actually how many devices were connected to the CPU in the early days (ie 1970s and 80s). Consider, however, a hard drive and its typical use. Typically a processor manipulates data that is stored in registers, but registers are not very big so for large amounts of data RAM is used as a high speed place to store data. The hard drive would be too slow for such use. If this data needs to be stored permenantly, however, then the data must be transferred from RAM to the hard drive. Using the method I specified above, the CPU would have to be constantly tied up transferring byte per byte the data it wants to store in the hard drive. This turned out to be quite painful in the early days, so a mechanism called Direct Memory Access (DMA) was created to allow devices to read and write from RAM directly. The CPU could simply send a command to the hard drive controller, for example, to read some section of the hard drive and put it in RAM or vice versa. The CPU then would be free to do other things while the HD did its business. The transfer was also alot faster than the old CPU based method.

So to answer your question: Are there other ways to connect devices? Absolutely! But you'll find that the fastest way to tranfer large amounts of data from a device is not through the Processor, but directly from the device to RAM, therefore most modern devices use RAM as an intermediary store.

Comment: "However, because the CPU would have to be constantly tied up just to transfer large blocks of data from devices to RAM"
What did you mean there? Why would the CPU be constantly tied up transferring large blocks of data to RAM? Were you still talking about not involving the RAM?

Comment: @mtanti I edited the answer for clarity on this matter. Basically RAM is the most useful area to manipulate large amounts of data and as such data from devices usually end up there anyway, thus the creation of DMA, although it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Great! Do you have a source I can look up more information from about this?

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessarily that way; for simple microcontrollers, or old computers such as the popular 80s microcomputers, the peripherals are attached directly to the address and data busses without storing the data in intermediate RAM. There may be an extra address decode line to distinguish between memory and peripherals, with corresponding instructions like the IN/OUT of x86.

Comment: What about secondary storage like hard disks? Are those necessarily accessed through the RAM?

Comment: In every modern or large design, yes. In old microcomputers, no; for example, the ZX spectrum tape interface the CPU read the "most recent" byte from an IO address then stored it to the "next" address it was loading to.

Comment: I thought that is the reason why it is called "secondary storage" because you can only access the data in it through the "primary storage" as in primary coming before secondary. Does the wording have nothing to do with how it is accessed?

Comment: It's more to do with _priority_ and _proximity_ : primary storage is accessible almost immediately, secondary storage has more space but takes a lot longer to access. I have heard of "tertiary storage" in tape libraries, where there is vast storage but it may have a latency of several minutes for a robot to find and load the tape.

Comment: @mtanti: Even if the data in secondary storage has to go through the processor before it goes to RAM, it will generally end up being stored to RAM before the processor can do anything "useful" with it.  For example, the Apple II floppy drive requires that the processor must read each byte of data within seven clock cycles of when it becomes available, and that seven-cycle window might start as few as 20 clock cycles after the previous byte is read.  The only way to do anything useful with the data on floppy is to read a bunch into RAM and then act upon it there.